# HTC WildFire Home Screen

Tags: home-screen, custom-roms, customization, htc-wildfire

Couple of weeks back I purchased HTC-WildFire. I did not find a way to change my default home screen. Is it possible to change my default home screen with my own custom screen. If it is possible I will write my own home screen for wild-fire.

Please suggest any mods, or procedures to change my home screen. Or is it possible with custom ROM's?

Answer (score 2):

1. On the Home Screen, tap

   ```
   Menu > Personalize Home Screen Tabs.
   ```
2. To move a tab, tap and hold the icon before the tab name, and then drag it up or down the tabs list.
3. To hide a tab, clear the check box at the right of the tab name.
4. Tap Done.

Answer (score 2):

Press the home button so all screens are shown, then long hold the screen you want as default home screen, then drag it to center of the screen and let go, hey presto.

Answer (score 0):

In most Android phones you can change your home screen. Simply download any "home screen replacement" app from the Market. You do not need to be rooted, nor install costum ROM.

Tips: download "Home Switcher" apps to easily change your home screen. If you don't use Home Switcher, you will need to go to `Settings > Applications > Manage application > **current home screen** > Clear defaults > Press Home button`. Hint: HTC Wildfire's home screen is HTC Sense